# SQL Command Error

Tags: mysql, select

I'm new with SQL, can anybody answer me what's the problem?! Thanks.

```
SELECT  
     bom.Parent_Material_Number, 
     mm.Material_Number, 
     mm.Material_Descr_HU,
     bom.Child_Material_Number
FROM mm,bom
GROUP BY mm.Material_Descr_HU
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Add the error you're getting.

Comment: The SQL qurey browser throw it:
Cant execute the query 
and nothing more :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. If you intend to use `GROUP BY` clause, be sure that the Ungroup fields have an aggregates such as `SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), etc`. See my example below:

```
SELECT  
      MIN(bom.Parent_Material_Number), 
      MAX(mm.Material_Number), 
      mm.Material_Descr_HU,
      MIN(bom.Child_Material_Number)
FROM  mm,bom
WHERE bom.Parent_Material_Number = mm.Material_Number
GROUP BY mm.Material_Descr_HU;
```

You can also an explicit join. See below:

```
    SELECT  
          MIN(bom.Parent_Material_Number), 
          MAX(mm.Material_Number), 
          mm.Material_Descr_HU,
          MIN(bom.Child_Material_Number)
    FROM mm INNER JOIN bom
    ON bom.Parent_Material_Number = mm.Material_Number
    GROUP BY mm.Material_Descr_HU;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you take records from two tables mm and bomz `FROM    mm,bomz` and have no join clause for this one in your statement.

Comment: Should i do like this?
`SELECT  bom.Parent_Material_Number, mm.Material_Number, mm.Material_Descr_HU,bom.Child_Material_Number
FROM    mm INNER JOIN bom
GROUP BY    mm.Material_Descr_HU`

Comment: No, it is an implicit join which is just an equivalent on what you're thinking right now.

Answer (score 0):

you need a JOIN or a WHERE clause to link the tables together